# Is this notation denoting multiplication or addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, notation

I am told to consider the set $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as a group under addition and the set $M_2(n\mathbb{Z})$ as a normal subgroup.

However I have no idea whether the second set is supposed to be $M_2(n+\mathbb{Z})$ or $M_2(n*\mathbb{Z})$

The full question is to show that $M_2(n\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to  $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_n)$

Answer (score 2):

What is likely is that the question asks you to show that the quotient $M_2(\mathbb{Z})/M_2(n\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_n)$.

If this is the case, then $n\mathbb{Z}$ indicates multiplicative multiples of $n$:
$$n\mathbb{Z}=\{\ldots, -n,0,n,2n,\ldots\}.$$
So, $M_2(n\mathbb{Z})$ is the subset of $2\times 2$ matrices such that each entry is a multiple of $n$.